# How to prevent the rounding of decimals when inserting into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a strange issue whereby each time I insert or update decimals into my database, the decimal values get rounded. For example if I insert `51.4988814`, it gets rounded to `51.00000000`.

The decimals in question are both latitude and longitude values.

The code I am using to insert into the database is:

```
$centre = Centre::updateOrCreate(
    ['wordpress_id' => $centre->ID],
    [
        'name' => $centre->post_title, 
        'postcode' => $centre->acf->postcode,
        'lat' => 51.4988814,
        'lng' => -0.1415936
    ]
);
```

The table migration looks like this:

```
Schema::create('centres', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('wordpress_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('postcode')->nullable();
    $table->decimal('lat', 10, 8);
    $table->decimal('lng', 11, 8);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

One attempt to fix this was to edit my `php.ini` and change the `precision=` to a higher number (25) and restart the server but this did not rectify the issue.

I have also tried using float instead of decimal in the database.

I have also tried

```
'lat' => (float)51.4988814,
'lng' => (float)-0.1415936
```

Inside the *updateOrCreate* function.

I am now out of ideas.

Edit:

I have added the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLES centres`

```
CREATE TABLE `centres` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `wordpress_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `postcode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `lat` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL,
 `lng` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Rounding in SQL With Decimal Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141160/prevent-rounding-in-sql-with-decimal-types)

Comment: Double-check your Centre model and make sure there's no mutators or anything else on those fields.

Comment: Are you going to do any mathematical operation with these values? If not, save as text...

Comment: @RussJ - They have already set the scale and precision in their migration: `$table->decimal('lat', 10, 8);`. `10` is the precision and `8` is the scale.

Comment: I know that you've shared your migration, which is good, but just to double-check, could you also provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE centres ` output?

Comment: @PatrickQ i've edited the post with the output

Comment: @Marcaum54 yes they will be used for mathematical operations

Comment: Change the decimal type to Varchar. It will fix that.